# delete subset from a table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the SQLite question which seems to be straightforward but cannot figure out: I have the following two tables
table A

```
ID1  ID2
a  b
a  c
b  c
e  f
```

table B

```
ID1  ID2
a  b
b  c
```

I want to delete elements in table B from table A using

```
Delete from A 
where (ID1,ID2) 
in (select * from B)
```

but sqllite gives a syntax error.

```
Your Query Result: Query failed to execute: near ',': syntax error
```

could you help me with the right clause I should use? Thanks!

Comment: The `IN` operator requires a ["single scalar operand on the left"](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op), and the subquery must have a single column; it will not match a list of values against a multi-column result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to USE the EXISTS Query.

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE a.ID1 = b.ID1 AND a.ID2 = b.ID2);
```

Tested with SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/67fc6/1

Comment: thanks for the help, as the whole structure of the query is more complex than this one, i am testing it now. will update shortly and it's good to learn something new, thanks!

Comment: -- update. this works like a charm! thanks Dirk. glad to learn the where exists clause